# What is my error in applying this Laplace Transform?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

So, our book has the seemingly innocuous problem: $y''-y'-6y=0$.  I was able to solve by hand, and come up with $${\scr L}(y)=\frac{s-2}{s^{2}-s+6}$$.That completed, I factored the bottom to $(s-3)(s+2)$.  Our professor gave us a sheet that said ${\scr L}\mathrm{{}f(t)\mathrm{}}=F(s)$ which corresponds along the rows to a column $f(t)$.  I broke the equation down to $$\frac{s}{(s-3)(s+2)}-\frac{2}{(s-3)(s+2)}$$ and the corresponding $f(t)$ were $$\frac{ae^{at}-be^{bt}}{a-b}$$ and $$\frac{e^{at}-e^{bt}}{a-b}$$, respectively.  The summation of these leads to:
$$\frac{1}{5}(-e^{2t}+5e^{-3t})$$.  However, the answer in the book is: $$\frac{1}{5}(e^{3t}+4e^{-2t})$$.

I have literally no idea why my method is working.  Would someone be so kind as to enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem given was to solve $y''(t)-y'(t)-6y(t)=0$ subject to initial conditions $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=-1$, using the Laplace transform, then we write $Y(s) =\mathscr{L}\{y(t)\}(s)$ and

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}\{y''(t)-y'(t)-6y(t)\}(s)&=\left(s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)\right)\\
&-\left(sY(s)-y(0)\right)\\
&-6Y(s)\\\\
&=(s^2-s-6)Y(s)-(s-2)\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

implies that

$$Y(s)=\frac{s-2}{s^2-s-6}=\frac15\left(\frac{1}{s-3}+\frac{4}{s+2}\right)$$

whereupon inverting reveals that $y$ is

$$y(t)=\frac15\left(e^{3t}+4e^{-2t}\right)$$

Comment: While I follow this quite easily, is seems like *both* this and my method should work?  Could you be so kind as to explicitly point out the error in mine?

Comment: Well, I'll try.  One issue is that the inverse Laplace transform of $sY(s)\ne y'(t)$, rather it is equal to $y'(t)+y(0)\delta (t)$.  Tell me what your values of $a$ and $b$ are; I presume $a=2$ and $b=-3$.

Comment: Indeed they were, although presumably you could switch them.

Comment: Well, another issue is that the inversions are not correct.  For example, for $\frac{-2}{(s-3)(s+2)}$ the inversion is $-\frac{2}{5}e^{3t}+\frac25 e^{-2t}$.  For $\frac{s}{(s-3)(s+2)}$ the inversion is $\frac{3}{5}e^{3t}+\frac25 e^{-2t}$.  I believe that you had the latter one correct, but forgot to multiply by $-2$ on the former.

Comment: If they had been, would I have gotten to an equivalent answer?

Comment: Yep!  You certainly would have.  Missed it by a factor of $-2$.  I cannot tell you how many times the small things get in the way.  The only advice is to proceed slowly, check and double check steps along the way.  Then, ask if the new result makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

For the differential equation $y'' - y' -6y = 0$ the Laplace transform is
\begin{align}
( s^2 y(s) - y'(0) - s y(0) ) - (s y(s) - y(0)) - 6 y(s) = 0
\end{align}
which leads to $(s^2 - s - 6) y(s) = y'(0) + y(0) (s-1)$ and
\begin{align}
y(s) &= \frac{y'(0) - y(0)}{s^2 - s -6} + \frac{y(0) \, s}{s^2 - s - 6}  \\
&= \frac{y'(0) - y(0)}{5} \left( \frac{1}{s-3} - \frac{1}{s+2} \right) + \frac{y(0)}{5} \left( \frac{2}{s+2} + \frac{3}{s-3} \right) \\
&= \frac{y'(0) + 2 y(0)}{5} \frac{1}{s-3} + \frac{3 y(0) - y'(0)}{5} \frac{1}{s+2}.
\end{align}
Inversion leads to
\begin{align}
y(t) = \frac{y'(0) + 2 y(0)}{5} \, e^{3t} + \frac{3y(0) - y'(0)}{5} \, e^{-2t}.
\end{align}

Comment: There appears to be an error in the calculation.  An $s$ was dropped from the term $sy(0)$.  As a consequence, the initial conditions of $y$ are not equal to the right-hand side.

Comment: There is still an error.  The second term's numerator ought to be $3y(0)-y'(0)$.

Comment: Yes!!   Now that is the correct answer.

Comment: @Dr.MV I was found the coefficient error after reading the first post. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.